# objective-cでの可変長配列について

Tags: xcode, objective-c

```
#define MV_GRID_LENGTH 1
#define MV_GRID_WIDTH 2

@interface ViewController (){
    UIImageView *imageView[ MV_GRID_LENGTH * MV_GRID_WIDTH ];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    int cnt = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<MV_GRID_LENGTH; i++){
        for(int j=0; i<MV_GRID_WIDTH;j++){
            imageView[cnt] = [UIImageView new];
            //処理中略

            [self.view addSubview:imageView[cnt]];
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

上記のようにimageViewを同時に複数生成するような処理において、imageViewの配列要素数が可変長になる場合、c言語では「UIImageView *imageView[];」のように表現すればよかったかと思いますが、objctive-cではどのように表現するのがよりよいのでしょうか。初歩的な質問で恐縮ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArrayというオブジェクトを追加、削除できるクラスが標準で備わっています。
コードの動作は確認していませんが、
以下のような感じになります。

```
NSMutableArray<UIImageView*> *imageViewArray = [NSMutableArray<UIImageView*> array];

for(int i=0; i<MV_GRID_LENGTH; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; i<MV_GRID_WIDTH;j++)
    {
        [imageViewArray addObject:[UIImageView new]];
        //処理中略

        [self.view addSubview:[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:cnt];
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。